# Please explain about class instance in c++

Tags: c++, class, header

```
class AAA
{
private:
    BBB<CCC> item;
....}
```

> Both BBB and CCC are other classes name of their header files.
>
> What
>   does "BBB< CCC > item;" means?

Comment: You mean: what does `BBB<CCC> item;` mean?

Comment: It looks like class AAA contains a private variable, BBB, which is a template class of type CCC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BBB`is a class that takes a template parameter. The template parameter is class `CCC`. That means `item` is a private variable of type `BBB<CCC>`.

Answer (score 1):

`<object>` mean genric programing, The object `BBB` getting class type `CCC` and it can be used in declaration of functions and variables in class `BBB`.

[More information here.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3862556/edit)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then how to initialize it in constructor?

Comment: @VitalPotion http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part#ClassTempl

Comment: Depends on its constuctor. But it is not different to a non-template class.

Answer (score 1):

item is a private member of type BBB< CCC >. BBB< CCC > is a class. BBB is a template class that requires a concrete class or data-type like int or CCC in this case.

BBB is defined as follows:

```
template <class T> class BBB
{
...
};
```

As an example, item can be initialized in the constructor of class AAA with any object of type BBB, in the following way:-

```
AAA(BBB<CCC> &bObj) : item(bObj)
{
...
}
```